# How to use GKPLugin to encode the video link?

Tags: javascript, html, video-processing, gkplugin

I am using GKPlugin. I want to know how to encode/hide the video src URL. I saw a code in a website which is using GKPlugin and he has encoded the videos URL. Here is the code of that website

```
<object id="flashplayer" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="640" height="480">
<param name="movie" value="http://watch32.com/media/player.swf" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="plugins=http://watch32.com/media/plugins_picasaweb/proxy.swf&proxy.link=watch32*161d164c16691671169d16221632166e177d17ac17ed184618de191319cb1a101a8a1a7c1bba1c6e1d191da61e691f0f1f2f20992194226c22952439251d256e2734282c29522a7c2b912c022dac2e802fcc31c032f434763581370e38b839943bbe3c9b3e23405641c6430e451846bb49054a3d4c3e4dbe4fc851f0537d55ec57da5a165c595e7a5feb62d064ec674e694b6bc46e08708e72e27531776d79767cae5328&skin=http://watch32.com/media/skins/lulu.xml&autostart=true&volume=100" />
<embed wmode="transparent" name="flashplayer" src="http://watch32.com/media/player.swf" FlashVars="plugins=http://watch32.com/media/plugins_picasaweb/proxy.swf&proxy.link=watch32*161d164c16691671169d16221632166e177d17ac17ed184618de191319cb1a101a8a1a7c1bba1c6e1d191da61e691f0f1f2f20992194226c22952439251d256e2734282c29522a7c2b912c022dac2e802fcc31c032f434763581370e38b839943bbe3c9b3e23405641c6430e451846bb49054a3d4c3e4dbe4fc851f0537d55ec57da5a165c595e7a5feb62d064ec674e694b6bc46e08708e72e27531776d79767cae5328&skin=http://watch32.com/media/skins/lulu.xml&autostart=true&volume=100" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="480" />
</object>
```

In this code he has encoded the video URL. I also want to encode/hide my video URL like this, For example this is the source of the video

```
http://www.mediafile.com/video/file1.mp4
```

I want this link to be shown like this

```
http://my_site.com/media/proxy.swf&proxy.link=my_site*153915681585158d15b9153e154e158a169916c81709176217fa182f18e7192c19a619981ad61b8a1c351cc21d851e2b1e4b1fb520b0218821b123552439248a26502748286e29982aad2b1e2cc82dd22f9f30f7321632cf34b2366037e938e33a773c713dcf3edf40e8429643ec45ec47c449744b244d434f3e511552db54e7570e58d25af45d185faf61296426666468616a866d306ee471c87408768678cb7bb25100
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why? That doesn't do you any good.

Comment: I want to know how to do this. 

This code above figures my purpose out.

Comment: You need to write a streaming proxy.

Comment: Can you give me an example for this? thank you so much. I really get hard work to understand what happened in this plugin.

Comment: You need to write server-side code that forwards HTTP requests from your encoded URLs to the original URL.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by asking the gkplugin developer for an encode plugin license.
It works perfectly.